# Можно ли полностью поменять дизайн Pycharm'a

Tags: pycharm

Вопрос немного странноват, но мне очень понравилось как выглядит это[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никто не знает, можно ли также в чарме сделать? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от того что конкретно вы хотите сделать.

Вот плагины с разными темами https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?tags=Theme

Темы из коробки доступны в **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Theme**.

Цветовую тему редактора можно руками поправить в **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Python**.